# Sloped Floor: Quick Fix for Bed and Desk

Tags: bedroom, desk

The room I'm in is about 8' wide x 16' long.  It slopes fairly heavily, primarily width-wise. The bed and the desk both go against the long wall, meaning the slope either results in a raised head or feet when sleeping, and I'm either pushed against the back of my chair or to the front. I've tried to ignore it, but it's starting to do damage to my legs and back.
I'm going to buy a bed frame with adjustable legs and use a level to level out the bed.(unless anyone has any better ideas).
But what about the table and chair? How can they both be level and on the same level as each other? I can't redo the floor. Are there any quick fixes? Any kind of large, adjustable chair/desk mat I could put underneath?

Comment: I'd insert [threaded feet](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-Yw%2BetOZL._SL500_AC_SS350_.jpg) into everything and call it a day. Just be aware that sliding heavy furniture on such hardware can result in tearing it out the side.

Answer (score 1):

Build a large "ramp" that has the same angle as the slope in the room. When the ramp is placed on the floor, the top of the ramp will be level. The high part of the ramp will probably be against the wall in your case, where the desk would sit. The low part would be out in the room and would be where your chair would go. You'll have to be careful not to wheel the chair off of the ramp, so you may want to add a small "curb". The tough part will be getting the angle right, but it doesn't need to be exact; in your case, any improvement may be better than what you have now